# Aggregating time sequences in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, window-functions

I am new to psql window functions and would like to perform a query on `test_table` in order to find out every instance of **inactive** outages per `mobile_id`, `country`, and `brand` and the duration of the outage in seconds.

Each outage should be treated as a separate event, in other words, when ordered by time, the appearance of an `active` row should reset the count.
If there is only a single standalone "inactive" record, there cannot be a `difftime` and these cases should be assigned a default of 60.

For example:

```
> test_table
   mobile_id    state country brand                time
1         1a inactive      dk nokia 2018-08-09 19:01:53
2         1a inactive      dk nokia 2018-08-09 18:51:39
3         1a   active      dk nokia 2018-08-09 18:42:10
4         1a inactive      dk nokia 2018-08-09 18:31:23
5         1a inactive      dk nokia 2018-08-09 18:21:27
6         2a   active      dk apple 2018-08-09 18:12:08
7         2a   active      dk apple 2018-08-09 18:01:45
8         2a   active      dk apple 2018-08-09 17:51:29
9         2a   active      dk apple 2018-08-09 17:41:27
10        2a inactive      dk apple 2018-08-09 17:31:32
11        3a   active      de nokia 2018-08-09 17:21:34
12        3a   active      de nokia 2018-08-09 17:11:48
13        3a   active      de nokia 2018-08-09 17:01:46
14        3a   active      de nokia 2018-08-09 16:51:31
15        3a   active      de nokia 2018-08-09 16:41:34
```

Querying the `test_table` would produce a result like this:

```
> outages
  id country brand diff_time
1  1      dk nokia       614
2  2      dk nokia       596
3  3      dk apple        60
```

How would one structure such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify the groups of inactives by taking the sum of the actives before them.  The rest is basically then aggregation:

```
select mobile_id, brand, country,
       least(extract(epoch from max(time) - min(time)), 60) as diff
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where state = 'active') over (partition by mobile_id, brand, country order by time) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by mobile_id, brand, country, grp;
```

Comment: This unfortunately only produces a result with diffs of either 0 or 60 - it doesn't take the duration of the outages

Comment: @the_darkside . . . This query cannot produce `0` because of the `least()`.